# ipaddress:port vs localhost:port when hosting silverlight Prism with WCF on IIS 7

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, iis, prism

This is probably very simple but bear with me.

When I deploy my **Silverlight 5 application with WCF** to IIS, using a simple copy and paste technique I can browse the web site flawlessly, but when I try to access it through ipaddress like this 192.168.1.3:8099 every single service call returns error such as this one:

```
An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.
  at .....
  at <MyNamespace>.OnGetSomethingFromDataBaseCompleted(Object state)
```

I can target the WCF services from other machines with success (192.168.1.3:8099/SomeService.svc). 
I wrote the test console app to call (and close) the service and it correctly gets some data from the remote DBServer.
Yet in browser nothing.

A should add that back from browser when navigate to 192.168.1.3:8099 Fiddler doesn't register this call but it does from localhost:8099.

**Can you help?**

I think that this is simple question for someone more experienced with deployment than me but if you think you should, please read on.

---

So you are reading on => (Prism).

I have a Silverlight application that connects to database calling WCF services (added as Silverlight WCF service - VSTemplate).

In this application I introduce Prism like [Jeremy Likness](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/) suggests on his [blog](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight.html)

I also use web proxies to access WCF services from ViewModel.

My project structure:

- WEB project
- SilverlightAppWithShell
- ModuleA
- ModuleB
- CommonProject

Deployment directory structure:

### C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAppFolder (IISUsers have accessToIt)

- .\bin\AllDlls
- .\ClientBin\AllXapFiles(XAP files from all projects mentioned above)
- .\Services\All *.cs files defining services operation contracts
- .\Web.config
- .\TestPage.html
- .\TestPage.aspx
- .\Silverlight.js
- .\AllServices *.scv files

and last but not least

- .\clientaccesspolicy.xml

with this code inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>"
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/Services" include-subpaths="true"/><!--I tried with App_Code here when renaming Services dir to App_Code with the same wain result-->
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: I am currently checking out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/08/09/using-relative-addresses-for-services-in-silverlight-applications.aspx)
I will let you know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing and solved my issue, following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/08/09/using-relative-addresses-for-services-in-silverlight-applications.aspx) post from Carlos Figueira. I am not sure if there is a better solution with Silverlight 5 but it works for me.

```
public static void UpdateMyServiceAddress(WebServiceMyProxies.MyServiceClient client)
        {
            client.Endpoint.Address = UpdateServiceAddress(client.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString());
        }

private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress UpdateServiceAddress(string originalAddress)
        {
            int svcIndex = originalAddress.IndexOf(".svc");
            int serviceNameIndex = originalAddress.LastIndexOf('/', svcIndex);
            string serviceName = originalAddress.Substring(serviceNameIndex + 1);

            string baseAddress = Application.Current.Host.Source.ToString();
            baseAddress = baseAddress.Substring(0, baseAddress.LastIndexOf('/')); // removing /App.xap
            baseAddress = baseAddress.Substring(0, baseAddress.LastIndexOf('/')); // removing /ClientBin

            return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", baseAddress,"Services", serviceName));
        }
```